# How to create Syntax Highlighting Text Box

Tags: c#

How to create a Syntax Highlighting Textbox Using C#.Net

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take [ScintillaNet](http://scintillanet.codeplex.com/) and take one of the [predefined lexer](http://scintillanet.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=HowToSyntax&referringTitle=Documentation) or write your own one ([example of IniLexer](http://scintillanet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/65868#1051338)). If you're going to adopt the sample you should also take a look into [this discussion](http://scintillanet.codeplex.com/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=42949).

Answer (score 2):

Making the Syntax highlighting textbox written in C#

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/FixingTheCode.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can actually use the ICSharpCode.TextEditor bundled with the Sharp Develop IDE source code. This is a fully-featured code editor. Using that control you can define your own syntax color rules and auto complete lookups.

Install the nuget package:

```
PM> Install-Package ICSharpCode.TextEditor
```

A good tutorial is available at http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30936/Using-ICSharpCode-TextEditor